# Hyper V Dedicated Network Traffic for Hyper V Replication between two Hyper V Server

Tags: networking, replication, windows-server-2019, hyper-v-server-2019

[our scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyXDL.png)

The scenario is applied exactly with our planning setting, we need to configure Replica on our VM inside Hyper-V, the issue is how to configure or dedicate a specific network for a replica that all data and traffic included (VMs) should be transferred from Physical Server 1 to Physical Server 2 through the 10G SFP+ ports that are connected directly between server’s in order not to affect on the main network that is connected through 1G Ethernet.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like overkill to me to be honest, but the answer to your question is just to configure the 10G SFP+ ports with IPs in a subnet which is specific to them, and then configure the Hyper-V replicas to use either those IPs or hostnames registered for those IPs.